# How to make a graph in matlab from a dataset?

Tags: matlab

You can ignore the first couple parts of the program as this is just a set up, you can go to the part where it gives you the first choice. So what im trying to do is make a bar graph of fifa teams and the amount of points that they have. The dataset is a 50x9 matrix. Im trying to have it graph all the rows (which is the amount of points) of column 4. However I keep experiencing an error. Ive never done bar graphs so I dont know how this work. I appreciate any inputs that you guys could give me.

```
fprintf('*loading dataset...\n');
fprintf('*analyzing dataset...\n');
data=dataset('File', 'thegrid2.txt', 'Delimiter', ',');
[rows cols] = size(data);

choice= menu('What would you like to see master?:', 'Graph 1', 'Graph 2', 'Graph 3', 'OR Graph 4')

if choice== 1
    x= 1:1:50;
    y= data(1:rows, cols-5);
    bar(x,y)
    title([ 'Countries vs. the amount of points: '])
    set(gca, 'Xtick', 1:1:50);
    set(gca,'XTickLabel', {'ESP','GER','ARG','CRO','POR','COL','ENG','ITA','NED','ECU','RUS','CIV','GRE','MEX','SUI','BEL','URU','FRA','BRA','DEN','BIH','GHA','CHI','SWE','CZE','MLI','MNE','USA','JPN','NOR','NGA','PER','HUN','ROU','ALG','VEN','UKR','PAN','IRL','SRB','TUN','KOR','PAR','TUR','ZAM','AUS','CRC','ALB','WAL','BFA'});
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First I'd plot using `barh` and not `bar` if you have 50 (!) labels to plot.
Second, if you need to plot only the 4th column, use, `y= data(:,4);`. For example:

```
data=rand(50,5);
x= 1:1:50;
y= data(:,4);
barh(x,y)
title([ 'Countries vs. the amount of points: '])
set(gca, 'Ytick', 1:1:50);
set(gca,'YTickLabel', {'ESP','GER','ARG','CRO','POR','COL','ENG','ITA','NED','ECU','RUS','CIV','GRE','MEX','SUI','BEL','URU','FRA','BRA','DEN','BIH','GHA','CHI','SWE','CZE','MLI','MNE','USA','JPN','NOR','NGA','PER','HUN','ROU','ALG','VEN','UKR','PAN','IRL','SRB','TUN','KOR','PAR','TUR','ZAM','AUS','CRC','ALB','WAL','BFA'});
ylim([0 51])
```

[image]

Comment: i get this error however when i try to use it with my dataset Error using dataset/subsrefParens (line 9)
Dataset array subscripts must be two-dimensional.

Error in dataset/subsref (line 69)
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = subsrefParens(a,s);

Error in xychk (line 95)
      if isvectorY,       y = y(:); end

Error in barh (line 54)
        [msg,x,y] = xychk(args{1:nargs},'plot');

Error in FINALPROJECT (line 12)
    barh(x,y)

Comment: seems like your dataset is not standard. try to convert to doubles by `data=double(data)`.